# When do I use XA datasource and 2 phase commit

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource, jta, xa

Can someone please explain the use of XA dataSource and how transaction management works in an XA datasource ? How is XA datasouce and 2 Phase commit related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two-phase commit and XA are more or less synonyms. They ensure that the ACIDity of a transaction is preserved even if this transaction involves several transactional systems such as, for example

- two databases
- a database and a JMS engine

To be able to participate in such a global transaction, each datasource must collaborate with the XA transaction manager, and must thus implement the XA protocol. If you need two-phase commit, you thus need an XA datasource.

Comment: Does this mean that If I have queries connecting to different DBs within the same transaction , I need to use an XA ?

Comment: If those queries modify both databases, then yes. Else one database commit might succeed while the other does not, causing a data incoherence.